# Obter determinada coluna a partir de um arquivo com múltiplas colunas

Tags: python

Pessoal possuo um arquivo de texto com algumas informações separadas por ';' por cada linha exemplo:

```
Nome;Email;Telefone;Endereço;Civil
```

Eu preciso 'filtrar' somente o 3 campo (Endereço pois começa do 0) de cada linha, como posso fazer isso?

Esse é meu código até o momento mas ele só pega a 4 letra das linhas:

```
def getParameters(dirBkp):
    x = 0
    with open(dirBkp, "r") as arq:
        for linha in arq:
            print(linha[3])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Com ele você consegue definir o separador das colunas e, inclusive, ler cada linha como um dicionário, facilitando a leitura do código.

```
import csv

def get_address_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
        reader = csv.DictReader(stream, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            yield row['Endereço']
```

Assim, se tiver um arquivo como, por exemplo:

```
Nome;Email;Telefone;Endereço;ECivil
Foo;foo@foo.com.br;0;Brasilia;Solteiro
Bar;bar@bar.com.br;0;Curitiba;Casado
```

Bastaria fazer:

```
for endereco in get_address_from_file('arquivo.txt'):
    print(endereco)
```

A saída seria:

```
Brasilia
Curitiba
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ElderlyUnawareList)</sup>

Você ainda pode generalizar a função passando o nome da coluna por parâmetro, caso precise acessar outras colunas em outros momentos:

```
def get_column_from_file(filename, column):
    with open(filename, 'r') as stream:
        reader = csv.DictReader(stream, delimiter=';')
        for row in reader:
            yield row[column]
```

E fazer:

```
for endereco in get_column_from_file('arquivo.txt', 'Endereço'):
    print(endereco)
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Anderson, salvou a minha vida rsrs

Comment: E cara só uma dúvida existe outra forma? Pois tem um outro script que le todas as linhas e faz outro processo =/

Comment: @WallaceBrunoGentil sim, há várias formas, depende do que precisa fazer. Da maneira que eu coloquei, como ele utiliza o `yield` na função, o retorno será um gerador, fazendo com que o arquivo não precise ficar inteiro na memória. Você pode ler arquivos de alguns megas ou gigas que funcionará sem problema. Depende apenas de quais são suas necessidades.

Comment: Mas então, como eu posso fazer sem que haja uma 1 linha com o dicionario?

Comment: Não entendi o que quis dizer.

Comment: No caso, o arquivo que eu tenho, já começa com os dados, não há um cabeçalho de dados informando o que cada campo simboliza, eu entendi o uso do CSV porém não vejo como usar esse recurso sem que haja um o cabeçalho entende?

Comment: Entendi. Você pode utilizar `csv.reader` ao invés de `csv.DictReader`, assim o retorno será uma lista ao invés de um dicionário, podendo acessar o endereço com `row[3]`.

Comment: Acabei de ver que na documentação ele mostra o reader e o Dictreader, desculpa o vacilo... falta de prestar atenção, muito obrigado por ter me mostrado o CVS rsrsrs vai me ajudar muito!